# Using Vector type in pgtyped

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, pgtyped

I have a database with an "embedding" column. This column is of vector type from pgvector. Now, pgtyped, the tool I am using to query the DB from my Node app, is giving me an error: `Error: Postgres type 'vector' is not supported by mapping`.

I have looked online and tried to find information on registering new types here, but have not found any resources that pertain to types wholly unfamiliar to pgtyped.